# Как работать с Laravel фронтенд пакетами?

Tags: json, laravel

После установки Laravel в package.json увидел разные пакеты, как работать с ними? и для чего они нужны?

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    }
}
```

Comment: Некоторые нужны, чтобы работали другие. Очень общий вопрос, трудно что-то сказать, чтобы помочь. Например с bootstrap вы можете работать в файле app.scss в app/resources/assets/sass/app.scss. А если интересны другие, то просто вбейте их названия в Гугле:)

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь много об этом:

http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/frontend

Разделы "Фронтенд" и "Сборка фронтенда"